# Can someone explain to me how this function works?

Tags: javascript, abstract, higher-order-functions

I'm learning to code and I'm trying to understand Higher Order Functions and abstractions.  I don't understand how this piece of code runs to return "true".

```
function greaterThan(n) {
  return function(m) { return m > n; };
}

var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);

console.log(greaterThan10(11));
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I understand m > n, I'm trying to understand how the values are assigned to m and n.

Comment: The inner function remembers its context by closure , so function knows the value of n and m you have passed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function `greaterThan` returns a function when called. The returned function has access to all the members of the outer function even after the function has returned. This is called [`closure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```
function greaterThan(n) {
    return function (m) {
        return m > n;
    };
}
```

When following statement is executed

```
var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
```

it is converted as

```
var greaterThan10 = function (m) {
    return m > 10;
};
```

So, `greaterThan10` is now the function and can be called as

```
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
```

Now, value of `m` is `11` and `return 11 > 10;` returns as `true`.

Read more about closures:

[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Also, I'll recommend following **great article** to all the JS developers

http://dmitryfrank.com/articles/js_closures