# Javascript one argument in function definition, but two arguments given

Tags: javascript

I am reading about closures right now and am confused by this javascript code.

```
function makeAdder(x) {
  return function(y) {
    return x + y;
  };
};

var add5 = makeAdder(5);
var add10 = makeAdder(10);

console.log(add5(2));  // 7
console.log(add10(2)); // 12
```

How does the console.log work? Since add5 = makeAdder(5), then isn't
add5(2)) = makeAdder(5)(2)?

I am wondering how y = 2 is determined by javascript in this function, as the function only defines one argument x.

EDIT: Sorry to make it clear, what I was confused about was the fact that it appears like 5 and 2 are both being passed into makeAdder(x).

Comment: `makeAdder` sets the value of `x` and returns the anonymous function. `add5` == `function (y) { return 5 + y };`

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753388/can-someone-explain-to-me-how-this-function-works/32753411#32753411. This might help you

Comment: makeAdder() returns a function that expects a single value, y.  makeAdder() is a closure around the function it returns, and it holds the value for x.  Not sure exactly what you're trying to ask...

Comment: Log `add5` (without parentheses) before your current loggings, you'll understand where `2` is passed.

Comment: See also [Make this syntax possible: var a = add(2)(3); //5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2272902/1048572)